# Second degree Taylor Polynomial Questions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

[image]

Hi so I was wondering if anyone could help me as I'm still not quite grasping the concept of these questions and I'm consistently getting the wrong answer.

So far this is what I have done:

$f(x,y)=e^{xy-2x+5y-6},  f(-1,1)=e^{0}=1$

$f_{x}(x,y)=(y-2)e^{xy-2x+5y-6},  f_{x}(-1,1)=-1$

$f_{y}(x,y)=(x+5)e^{xy-2x+5y-6},  f_{y}(-1,1)=4$

$f_{xx}(x,y)=(y-2)^2e^{xy-2x+5y-6},  f_{xx}(-1,1)=1$

$f_{yy}(x,y)=(x+5)^2e^{xy-2x+5y-6},  f_{yy}(-1,1)=16$

$f_{xy}(x,y)=(x+5)(y-2)e^{xy-2x+5y-6},  f_{xy}(-1,1)=-4$

so then I put my answer together and obtain:

$P_{2}(x,y)= 1-(x+1)+4(y-1)+(1/2)(x+1)^2-4(x+1)(y-1)+(16/2)(y-1)^2$

which I have found to be incorrect as the given answer is:

$P_{2}(x,y)=-4-x+4y+8(y-1)^2+1/2(x+1)^2-3(x+1)(y-1)$

So no I'm completely stuck on where I went wrong. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual discrepancy between the two expressions is just the value of $f_{xy}$, otherwise it is just a matter of simplification (and I would say your answer is actually the "better" answer in that aspect). As for why that happened, there is a product rule application required to find $f_{xy}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I totally see where I have gone wrong here in forgetting the product rule .